# JSON Web Token (JWT) with HMAC protection - causing error with version 4.23

Tags: nimbus

I was using `nimbus-jose-jwt` version `3.12` earlier and below code was working great. But when I updated `nimbus-jose-jwt` version `4.23` I see the following error coming

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor JWTClaimsSet() is undefined
    The method setSubject(String) is undefined for the type JWTClaimsSet
    The method setIssuer(String) is undefined for the type JWTClaimsSet
    The method setExpirationTime(Date) is undefined for the type JWTClaimsSet

    at springdemo.jwt.JWTWithHMACProtection.test(JWTWithHMACProtection.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I am not sure what code should I need to modify, please guide

The code for reference:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws KeyLengthException {
        // Generate random 256-bit (32-byte) shared secret
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] sharedSecret = new byte[32];
        random.nextBytes(sharedSecret);

        // Create HMAC signer
        JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(sharedSecret);

        // Prepare JWT with claims set
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
        claimsSet.setSubject("alice");
        claimsSet.setIssuer("https://c2id.com");
        claimsSet.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000));

        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), claimsSet);

        // Apply the HMAC protection
        signedJWT.sign(signer);

        // Serialize to compact form, produces something like
        // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ.onO9Ihudz3WkiauDO2Uhyuz0Y18UASXlSc1eS0NkWyA
        String s = signedJWT.serialize();

        // On the consumer side, parse the JWS and verify its HMAC
        signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(s);

        JWSVerifier verifier = new MACVerifier(sharedSecret);

        Assert.assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));

        // Retrieve / verify the JWT claims according to the app requirements
        Assert.assertEquals("alice", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
        Assert.assertEquals("https://c2id.com", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());
        Assert.assertTrue(new Date().before(signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this issue. Simply use the below code. Done! Its with the latest code

```
@Test
    public void test() throws JOSEException, ParseException {
        // Generate random 256-bit (32-byte) shared secret
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] sharedSecret = new byte[32];
        random.nextBytes(sharedSecret);

        // Create HMAC signer
        JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(sharedSecret);

        // Prepare JWT with claims set
        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                 .subject("alice")
                 .issuer("https://c2id.com")
                 .expirationTime(addOneHour(new Date()))
                 .claim("http://example.com/is_root", true)
                 .build();

        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), claimsSet);

        // Apply the HMAC protection
        signedJWT.sign(signer);

        // Serialize to compact form, produces something like
        // eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ.onO9Ihudz3WkiauDO2Uhyuz0Y18UASXlSc1eS0NkWyA
        String token = signedJWT.serialize();
        System.out.println("Token : "+token);

        // On the consumer side, parse the JWS and verify its HMAC
        signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);

        JWSVerifier verifier = new MACVerifier(sharedSecret);

        Assert.assertTrue(signedJWT.verify(verifier));

        // Retrieve / verify the JWT claims according to the app requirements
        Assert.assertEquals("alice", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject());
        Assert.assertEquals("https://c2id.com", signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer());

        Date date1 = new Date();
        Date date2 = signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime();

        Assert.assertTrue(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0);
    }

    private Date addOneHour(Date currentDate){
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(currentDate);
        Date plusOnehour = dateTime.toDate();
        return plusOnehour;
    }
```